# Values on the frist day of the week

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake like below

```
StockName    Date          Value

GOOG         10/12/2021     $100
GOOG          10/11/2021     $995
```

Now i want to create  a new column which would give me results that would show the value  of the stock on weeks first day which would be monday or the next day if monday is a holiday

```
StockName         date          Value        value_weekstart
GOOG              10/12/2021    $1000         $995
GOOG              10/11/2021    $995          $995
```

Comment: Do you have a table (or access to data that could be loaded) that would tell you which days are holidays....I assume in this case "stock market closed" days?  Otherwise, you can use `dayofweek` function in Snowflake, but the exceptions aren't available as a native function.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
SELECT 
    stockname,
    date,
    value,
    FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITON BY stockname, datetrunc('week',date) ORDER BY dayofweekiso(date)) as value_weekstart
FROM table_name
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

that will return the "sunday price" if there is one, but will side step the possible jump if you use the stock `dayofweek` and someone changes the setting on your instance.

If you really want sunday to be last going to `(dayofweekiso(date)+6)%7` will roll it around to last position.

Comment: literally had this typed out to submit...you beat me to it.  :-)

Comment: Thank you. But when i tried the  same and if i am using a single day as filter it is bringing me the value for the  day instead of the value corresponding to the first day of the week

Comment: @Scout75 I am puzzled, this code has to see all the values for the week to get the first value of that week. so if you are going to add a "only one day filter" you will have to structure the query in a different shape. A cte more likely at that point makes more sense.

Comment: how about some case statements mixed into there? Copied from a solution I have

     , case when last_day(as_of) = as_of then 1
       else 0 end as month_lastday
     , case when last_day(as_of, 'week') = as_of then 1
       else 0 end as week_lastday
     , case when dayname(as_of) = 'Mon' then 1
       else 0 end as week_firstday

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake not sure how that relates to this problem but I would tend to use the IFF form `IFF(LAST_DAY(as_of) = as_of, 1, 0) AS month_lastday,
IFF(LAST_DAY(as_of, 'week') = as_of, 1, 0) AS week_lastday,
IFF(DAYNAME(as_of) = 'Mon', 1, 0) AS week_firstday` or just the boolean values directly `LAST_DAY(as_of) = as_of AS month_lastday,
LAST_DAY(as_of, 'week') = as_of AS week_lastday,
DAYNAME(as_of) = 'Mon' AS week_firstday`

Comment: I created a CTE on top of it  and it worked . Thanks everyone.